# MongoDB Only show equal fields when they exist

Tags: json, mongodb

How do you only show those that exist?

This is my current code:
`db.collection.find({ $expr: {$eq: ["fieldA", "fieldB"]}, {"_id":0, "fieldC":1})`

I have been trying things like the below but unsure of the correct syntax

`db.collection.find({ $expr: {$eq: {$exists: ["fieldA", "fieldB"]}}, {"_id":0, "fieldC":1})`

`db.collection.find({ $expr: {$eq: ["fieldA": {$exists: true}, "fieldB": {$exists: true}]}}, {"_id":0, "fieldC":1})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
 $match: {
    $and: [
      {
        "fieldA": {
          $exists: true
        }
      },
      {
        "fieldB": {
          $exists: true
        }
      },
      {
        $expr: {
           $eq: [
              "$fieldA",
              "$fieldB"
           ]
         }
       }
      ]
     }
    }
 ])
```

Explained:
and:[ {exist(A)} ,{exist(B)} ,{A=B?}  ]

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CfFHU8f7T8G)

Comment: this is great thank you, I should have thought of that syntax, I haven't found the correct way to only print some fields though. Do you know where I put that in the brackets? I have tried ...aggregate([{...}, {"_id":0}]) and ...aggregate([{...}], {"_id":0}) and ...aggregate([{$match: {...}, {"_id":0}}])
Thanks!

Comment: You need to add project stage aa follow  aggregate([ {},{}, {$project:{_id:0}} ])

Comment: got it thank you very much! I have another question you might find simple if interested (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71538159/mongodb-using-duplicate-function-to-print-different-field)