# MongoDB using duplicate function to print different field

Tags: arrays, json, database, mongodb, mongodb-query

`db.collection.aggregate([{"$group" : {"_id": "$fieldA", "count": {"$sum": 1}}},{"$match":{"_id" :{"$ne":null}, "count" : {"$gt":1}}},{"$project": {"fieldA":"$_id", "_id" : 0}}]);`

I am currently using this code to find duplicates however I actually want to print fieldB and not fieldA. By using the above I believe I have created a subset? Is there a simple way to print only fieldB?

ie. I want to print `{"_id":0, "fieldB":1}`

The only method I can think of is naming this subset and then joining with the original and then printing just fieldB but that doesn't seem efficient.

Comment: if you group on fieldA , only fieldA will be available to print , you need to group on fieldB to be able to print fieldB ...

Comment: right thank you, so there wouldn't be a way to find duplicates only in fieldA and then print only fieldB?

Comment: the question is: which fieldB , since you are grouping by fieldA  , for count >1 there will be more fieldB for field A , you may add in the group stage one more field that contain all fieldB($push)  per fieldA  or you may get $last fieldB per fieldA ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the last fieldB you can do something like this:

$last:
[playground1](https://mongoplayground.net/p/m31RA1GhGS-)
( But here if there is different fieldB per duplicated fieldA you will not find out )

Or to see the all fieldB for the duplicated filedA you can do something like this:

$push:
[playground2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QJzsENTPz4L)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
"$group": {
  "_id": "$fieldA",
  "count": {
    "$sum": 1
  },
  fieldB: {
    $push: "$fieldB"
  }
 }
},
{
 "$match": {
  "_id": {
    "$ne": null
   },
  "count": {
    "$gt": 1
   }
  }
 },
 {
  "$project": {
  "fieldA": "$_id",
  "fieldB": 1,
  "_id": 0
  }
 }
])
```